# Different Javascript behavior between Chrome/iOS and Chrome/MacOS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Loading this page http://malt.chat/x.html on Chrome/macOS displays "Hello, it works"

Loading this page on Chrome/iOS displays "ReferenceError: Cannot find variable: Two"

Why?

```html
<div id=hello></div>

<script>
  class One {
    static one() {
      document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = "Hello, it works";
    }
  }
  class Two {
    static two() {
      One.one();
    }
    // removing this line eliminates the ReferenceError in iOS
    static s = 10;
  }
</script>

<script>
  try {
    Two.two();
  } catch (err) {
    document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = err;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It's because static member variable declarations are not supported outside the constructor yet.

Comment: chrome on ios is still webkit/safari